# Any downsides to saving your Redux store in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, redux

I'm working on a project that includes many generated elements, keyframes and interactions between those elements. The parent elements are constants and hold basic values such as ’id’, ’name’, ’shape’ etc. Generated elements hold information about their size, position and color.

If it weren't for mongo, I'd probably store all the generated data in a JSON file. Would there be any disadvantages to storing the data in Mongo as it's currently in the redux store without any denormalization applied?

Comment: Its probably not a problem. One consideration is if its likely to grow over the 16mb document limit. I assume that would be very unlikely, but its the only concern I can think of

Comment: Then why would one ever want to keep this type of data nested and having to bother to normalize it when it's loaded in the app and then denormalize it when it's time to save?